# how to make svn diff show only non-whitespace line changes between two revisions

Tags: svn, diff, whitespace

I can get diffs between two revisions using something like

```
svn diff -r 100:200 > file.diff
```

But the problem is that there are many lines that show up due to change in whitespace. Is there a way to only write those lines that actually change in a significant way and not just in whitespace?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use

```
svn diff -r 100:200 -x -b > file.diff
```

If you want to ignore all whitespaces:

```
svn diff -x -w | less
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1741774/1763602)

Comment: Is that new for 1.6? SVN never use to do that. I should keep more current :)

Comment: 1.5.4 does it. But: --ignore-space-change, not --ignore-space-changes

Comment: @Dan McG. Do not know if is new for 1.6, but entry number 8 at http://www.akatombo.com/en/comments/ignore_whitespace_in_a_subversion_diff/ suggest that it is available since 1.4

Comment: @ur. Sure. Sorry for the typo. Corrected.

Comment: Just a comment, that "-x" argument sure has confusing semantics: when used after --diff-cmd diff, "-x" means "pass the next argument to diff". When used without, it means "pass the next argument to our internal implementation of diff, which happens to have some of the same syntax as real diff". Ugh.

Comment: Is there any way to make this the default for `svn diff`, so I don't have to say `-x -b` every time?

Comment: Because EOL may be considered whitespace as well, adding ``-x --ignore-eol-style`` might be necessary if EOL style is different between revisions.

Comment: When you also want to suppress any newlines introduced or removed you should use an external diff program and add some options `svn diff --diff-cmd '/usr/bin/diff' -x '-u --ignore-all-space --ignore-blank-lines' path1 path2` (-u gives the unified style as does svn diff)

Comment: Using `svn diff -x -w` can sometimes also be useful, as it ignores more whitespace (alias for ignore-all-space)

Answer (score 75):

Use `-x --ignore-space-change` or `-x --ignore-all-space`. (See `svn -h diff`.)

Comment: `svn diff -x -w` == `svn diff -x --ignore-all-space`

Answer (score 9):

You can use an alternate diff command using the --diff-cmd argument for svn diff.  diff is a good utility that has plenty of features for ignoring whitespace.

For example:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-w"
```

Comment: actually i used svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-w" -r 2000:2100 > jj1 and it works. thanks

Comment: @umar: This is the only way that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Note that end-of-lines are not considered whitespace in this scenario and that has to be ignored with:

```
svn diff -x --ignore-eol-style [etc...]
```